# Manually Selecting through Program the Video Quality in HTTP Adaptive Streaming

Tags: video-streaming, multimedia, http-streaming

Just wondering what are the possibilities of manually selecting the Video Quality in Adaptive HTTP Streaming using a program for different segments of the video.

For example, how is it possible that I select 1000 kbps video for first 60 seconds of video and then select 600 kbps video for the next 40 seconds and then may be 800 kbps for next 60 seconds.

I understand that in Adaptive Streaming the Quality of Video is selected Automatically based on Network Conditions.. the same client can receive High Quality video initially but when the Network Condition changes, the Video Quality can be reduced to Lower Quality.

I just want to take control of this Decision Making about Quality of Video, How is that possible. I am not a Multimedia guy. But I really need to do this.

Help will really appreciated.

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP adaptive streaming videos are cuttet into segments. One segment could be e.g. 15 seconds. 
A video is made out of a sequence of one keyframe and after that a lot of frames which do not contain the whole picture but only the discrepancy to the frame before. The frequency of keyframes can be choosen by the encoder, lets say in this case every 125Frames (=every 5 seconds at 25FPs). Each segment starts with such a keyframe (which does not mean that a segment cannot contain more than one keyframe).
The player detects the network quality and if there were a to bad network quality during downloading of the last segment (e.g. the video stopped because of buffering or a metering showed a to small bandwith) the player will load a lower quality video. Or if there is a better quality video available and the player detects e.g. through metering that it is possible to geht the better video it will take the better one. After e.g. 15 seconds there is a new segment and the whole procedure starts again.

This a very general description but I thought you first should understanding the magic behind adaptive streaming in general.

Q: What is a reasonable reason to manipulate adaptive streaming? - I can't imagine one, but please tell us.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not receive any answer for long time so stopped checking it. I am interested in building a system, in which I can dictate or force to change the quality after say 180 seconds - rather than player deciding to lower the quality. I am wondering if I can take that control in any way.